# How to reduce latency with fast short queries in Postgresql 15.3 on a NUMA server

Tags: postgresql, numa

We're running two different versions of Postgresql on two separate servers:

- Server A: Postgresql 9.3
- Server B: Postgresql 15.3

Server B is way more powerful than server A:

- Server A: 1x Intel Xeon E3-1270 3.5GHz, 2x 8GB DDR3, RAID0
- Server B: 2x Intel Xeon Platinum 8260 2.4GHz, 4x 16GB DDR4, RAID1

When we run fast short `SELECT` queries (< 1 ms) on both servers, server A is consistently running faster than server B, even if the query plans are exactly the same:

Server A:

```
# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "foobar" WHERE ("foobar"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1;
                                                                         QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: (1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5
   ->  Index Only Scan using foobar_pkey on public.foobar  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: 1
         Index Cond: (foobar.id = 1)
         Heap Fetches: 1
         Buffers: shared hit=5
 Total runtime: 0.017 ms
(9 rows)

Time: 0.281 ms
```

Server B:

```
# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "foobar" WHERE ("foobar"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1;
                                                                         QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: 1
   Buffers: shared hit=4
   ->  Index Only Scan using foobar_pkey on public.foobar  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: 1
         Index Cond: (foobar.id = 1)
         Heap Fetches: 0
         Buffers: shared hit=4
 Planning Time: 0.110 ms
 Execution Time: 0.045 ms
(10 rows)

Time: 0.635 ms
```

RAID1 could add some latency on server B if we were reading from disk, but we've confirmed these queries are hitting the buffer/cache and therefore reading data from memory and not from disk. We've checked the hit rate with the following query:

```sql
SELECT 
 'cache hit rate' AS name, 
 sum(heap_blks_hit) / (sum(heap_blks_hit) + sum(heap_blks_read)) AS ratio 
FROM 
 pg_statio_user_tables;
```

The latency is quite low on both servers, but when you're running a bunch of fast short queries concurrently, on aggregate you see the difference, with server A being 0.1-1.0 seconds faster on average than server B.

Server B has 2 CPUs and is using NUMA on Linux. Maybe that's adding some overhead/latency? Transparent Huge Tables is set to 'madvise' on Linux and `huge_pages` is set to `try` on Postgresql.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, the latency was due to the [CPU governor](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt). It was set to 'powersave' by default. Changing it to 'performance' made the server more responsive. You have further instructions [here](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/11/09/how-to-set-cpu-governor-at-boot/).